# How to post an object to Jersey Rest Service

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a Jersey Web Service with the following signature:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response save(Student a) {...}
```

I want to make a POST request in my java code using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient and pass a Student object. How can I go about doing this? I found plenty of examples that post a string as namedvaluepair. But not so clear on how a custom object can be posted. Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to dmy test, the body is in JSON format. so convert your Student object into JSON data.

```
public String post(String url, HashMap<String, String>params, String body) throws Exception {
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);

    for(String key : params.keySet()){
        postRequest.addHeader(key, params.get(key));
    }

    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(body);
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    postRequest.setEntity(input);

    HttpResponse response = (new DefaultHttpClient()).execute(postRequest);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

    String output;
    StringBuffer totalOutput = new StringBuffer();
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        totalOutput.append(output);
    }
    return totalOutput.toString();    
}
```